# How do I save multiple csv files into a user folder?

Tags: python, csv, directory, user-input, export-to-csv

I have a code that creates csv files but I'm not sure how to save the csv files in a user folder. My code creates it, but the csv files are not in the folder. Here is my code so far.

```
with open('driverInfoDC.csv', mode='w', newline = '') as file:

    writer = csv.writer(file)
    driver.writerow(["cities", "name", "milesDriven"])
    driver.writerow(["Greensborrow", "Peter", "6"])
    driver.writerow(["Winsdow", "Tony", "7"])
    driver.writerow(["Marlboro", "Esther", "8"])

with open('driverInfoVA.csv', mode='w', newline = '') as file:

    writer = csv.writer(file)
    driver.writerow(["cities", "name", "milesDriven"])
    driver.writerow(["Greensborrow", "John", "6"])
    driver.writerow(["Winsdow", "Jacob", "3"])
    driver.writerow(["Marlboro", "Summer", "10"])

    os.chdir(C:\Users\Documents\Trial\*.csv)

    user_folder = input('Please specify the folder to put the files in: ')

    os.mkdir(user_folder)
```

Comment: When you open the files for writing, use their full path names that includes the target destination folder (don't bother with `os.chdir`). Alternatively, you could do the `chdir` _before_ opening the files.

Comment: so like this?                                                                                                                   with open('C:\Users\Documents\Trial\driverInfoDC.csv\*.csv', mode='w', newline = '') as file:

Comment: Sort of, but don't use actual wildcard characters like that and you'll need to double the backslash characters like this: `'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Trial\\driverInfoDC.csv'` **or** use add an `r` prefix to the string like: `r'C:\Users\Documents\Trial\driverInfoDC.csv'`.

Comment: will that be able to have the files saved on the user's folder